# The avatar on my posts is hiding from me!

Tags: bug, profile-picture, gravatar

So I just noticed that the avatar on all my posts looks like this:

[image]

... but only for myself. Other people still see my actual avatar.
I also see the correct avatar in chat.

How can I entice my avatar to come out of hiding?

Comment: This is a problem with Gravatar that we have no control over.